# Scroll to WPF elements outside boundary

Tags: wpf, canvas, window, scroll

I'm editing a WPF Window object in Visual Studio and have a canvas element that stretches outside the boundary of the Window. Visual Studio only gives a zoom in/out feature, but I can't scroll left or right, even though my canvas inside the Window stretches way off the right of the screen. How can I scroll out all that way?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Your big canvas must be contained in another container with a constrained size. Try to set `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` on the window.